# What are the rules of the mysterious game with "phát tài" written on the box?

Tags: identify-this-game

I bought this game in a small grocery store in Vietnam. I've asked several Vietnamese people of various age if they know the game. Usually, they knew the game but didn't know the rules.

My questions are:

- **What is the name of this game?**
- **What are the rules of this mysterious game?**

These are the photographs of the game itself. Perhaps they'll help you to identify the game and provide me with a set of rules.

## Box

The box is not big. It has some Vietnamese words on it:

- The title is: *phát tài*
- The text on the top of the box is: *chính hiệu cao cáp; dề phòng giả mạo*
- The words in the four octagons between two children on the side of the box are:

  - *cung*
  - *hỉ*
  - *phát*
  - *tài*

[image: the "phát tài" side of the box]
[image: the "Chinese characters" side of the box]
[image: the "all plastic" size of the box]
[image: the top of the box]
[image: the bottom of the box]
[image: yet another view on the box]

## Content of the Box

There are ten matchboxes inside the main box - a half of them is green and the second half is red.

The Vietnamese words on the matchboxes are:

- *phát tài* on one side of the matchbox;
- *thuận thiên* on the other side;
- *thuận thiên* on the bottom.

[image: matchbox-like small boxes]￼

## Inside the matchbox

Every matchbox has 4 sets of 28 cards of different colors: green, red, white and yellow.

It is written *phát tài* on the back of every card.

[image: a matchbox]
[image: 4 different colors]
[image: the back of the card]
[image: 12 sample cards]

---

<sup>Note: To view the images in a higher resolution, just remove the last `m` character from the link to imgur. For example change *https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1vKV**m**.jpg* to *https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1vKV.jpg*.</sup>

Comment: I'm disappointed that used a pen instead of a "[standard reference cat](http://miniset.net/files/cfp-updates/228159.jpg)" as the creators of Scythe used ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your game is probably related to [Four Color Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Color_Cards) (Tứ sắc in Vietnam) since it uses similar very narrow cards in those colors.